# Can a Service Worker pre-cache a MySQL database?

Tags: javascript, mysql, service-worker

I have a PWA that utilizes service workers. It can pre-cache URLs and assets which I find super useful especially since I've transitioned it to a TWA and published it on the Play Store.

The MySQL db it connects to is fairly light at around 6mb.

Is it possible to pre-cache the full database with my Service Worker or is it only possible to pre cache URLs/Static Assets?

Comment: You can cache anything that "looks like" a static resource. So the JSON that is returned from a request can be cached. I think the limitation you'll run into is the per-origin browser storage limitation - which is implementation specific.

Comment: Yeah I'm currently caching all the JSON responses but there could be 1000s of variations depending on what is searched. So if someone goes offline and tries to search for something they haven't yet viewed, then I can't figure out a way around it.

Comment: Have you entertained the idea of moving your MySQL DB into IndexDB or WebDB in the browser? Might be the best solution of all. Update the browser DB at cache time with full DB, then query browser DB for search? Would be the best of both worlds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Service workers can cache/precache the response of a given request.
Let's say you have `Library` MySQL database on the server, containing tables like `Books` and `Authors`.  In order to cache it using a service worker you could create a service that returns books and authors in JSON format, e.g. `GET https://you-api.com/library`. Then depending on your caching strategy you can either:

- Add `https://you-api.com/library` URL to the list of precached resources used in service worker's `install` step, or
- Handle service worker's `fetch` event corresponding to the `https://you-api.com/library` request.

In either case you can store the result in `Cache` or `IndexedDB`. I would prefer `IndexedDB` though, since we need to be able to work conveniently with this data later on. With IndexedDB you can create several stores if you decide to store your MySQL table records separately.

OK, we have created and populated our local database. Now what?

You could either:

- Query local `Library` database directly from your page, or
- **Keep using service workers**

Let's focus on the second option. Your app most likely uses some services to fetch data from the remote database. Let's say `https://you-api.com/library/book/<id>` service is used to retrieve a book by id. Why not take advantage of the fact that we have books cached locally? The most straightforward approach would be to:

- Intercept fetch request corresponding to the URL above using service worker above
- Read the table name and book id from the request URL
- Query local `Library` database for that specific book and return it in the same format as the remote service would

Some additional considerations and corner cases:

- Handle the case when local database is not present
- Decide when and how the database is updated
- Deal with schema changes
- Optionally employ network first strategy. Attempt to retrieve database records from the remote service first and fallback to cached version when network is not available